# How can I set column type when using SqlBulkCopy to insert into a sql_variant column

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, datatable, sqlbulkcopy, sql-variant

I'm using SqlBulkCopy to insert/update from a .net DataTable object to a SQL Server table that includes a sql_variant column.  However SqlBulkCopy insists on storing DateTime values put into that column as sql type 'datetime' when what I need is 'datetime2'.

My DataTable is defined like this:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VariantValue", typeof(object))); //this represents my sql_variant column
```

Then I throw some data in there that requires a 'datetime2' to store.

```
DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
row[0] = DateTime.MinValue;
dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

And then I use SqlBulkCopy to get that data into Sql Server:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnection))
{
     bulk.DestinationTableName = "tblDestination";     
     bulk.WriteToServer(dataTable);     
}
```

My bulk copy will fail if a DateTime value is present in the data table that falls outside the range of the sql 'datetime' type (such as '1/1/0001').  That's why the column needs to be of type 'datetime2'.

When you're writing normal insert statements that insert into a sql_variant column you can control what the type of the variant column is by using CAST or CONVERT.  For example:

```
insert into [tblDestination] (VariantValue) values (CAST('1/1/0001' AS datetime2))
```

Then if you were to display the actual type of the variant column like this:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'BaseType') AS basetype FROM test
```

You'd see that indeed it is being stored as a 'datetime2'.

But I'm using SqlBulkCopy and, as far as I know, there's no place to tell it that .net DateTime objects should be stored in columns of type 'datetime2' and not 'datetime'.  There's no place on the DataTable object, that I know of, to declare this either.  Can anyone help me figure out how to get this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MSDN page for [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) (under "Remarks"):

> SqlBulkCopy will fail when bulk loading a DataTable column of type
>   SqlDateTime into a SQL Server column whose type is one of the
>   date/time types added in SQL Server 2008.

So, `SqlBulkCopy` won't be able to handle `DateTime2` values.  Instead, I'd suggest one of two options:

1. Insert each row individually (i.e. use a `foreach` on your DataTable), handling the datatype there.  (It might help to use a stored proc to wrap the insert and utilize `SqlCommand.Parameters` to type the data for the insert.)
2. Bulk insert into a temp table of strings, then transfer the data to your primary table (converting data types as necessary) in SQL. (which I think will get unnecessarily complicated, but you *may* be able to eek out some performance for large datasets)

Comment: Well that stinks.  I hope they get around to updating SqlBulkCopy.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yeah, I've always found SQL Server's bulk insert abilities lacking.  If your input data is from a file, you might try looking into some SSIS options as well.