# SqlBulkCopy and datetime2 target database column

Tags: sql-server, datatable, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

If you look at this Microsoft Documentation article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5.2

in the Remarks section it says:

> SqlBulkCopy will fail when bulk loading a DataTable column of type
>   SqlDateTime into a SQL Server column whose type is one of the
>   date/time types added in SQL Server 2008.

I am not observing this behavior (failure) and would like to know whether this documentation is possibly obsolete and SqlBulkCopy has been updated to support these data types.

More details on what I do:

- I create DataTable as a source for SqlBulkCopy. The DataTable column
  is of type **System.DateTime**.
- Target column in database table is of type **datetime2**.
- I use .Net 4.5 and SQL Server 2016 SP1

Everything just works. I get no failures. I even tried passing "01/01/0001" date (outside of the range for SQL **datetime** type) in the DataTable and it gets saved as such in database.

I did find this 8 years old SO post: [How can I set column type when using SqlBulkCopy to insert into a sql_variant column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941661/how-can-i-set-column-type-when-using-sqlbulkcopy-to-insert-into-a-sql-variant-co) but I am not using **sql_variant** and nothing fails in my case.

Can anyone clarify what Microsoft documentation I quoted means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SqlBulkCopy will fail when bulk loading a DataTable column of type [`SqlDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime?view=netframework-4.5.2) into a SQL Server column whose type is one of the date/time types added in SQL Server 2008.

But you wrote the type of your column is `System.DateTime` - so this remark is not relevant to your code.

In other words, if you created your data table like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("date column", typeof(SqlDateTime));
// ... other columns here
```

Then it would be relevant to your code.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly it - I misunderstood what documentation meant. I changed my DataTable column type from System.DateTime to SqlDateTime to test and SqlBulkCopy failed with exception message saying about being unable to convert from datetime to datetime2.

Comment: Glad to help :-)